# java : Inside Enhanced for loop cannot Object to String

Tags: java

I have taken this example from net .
But when i tried it is not compiling saying cannot convert Object to String

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList names = new ArrayList();

        names.add("Amy");
        names.add("Bob");
        names.add("Chris");
        names.add("Deb");
        names.add("Elaine");
        names.add("Frank");
        names.add("Gail");
        names.add("Hal");

        for (String nm : names)
            System.out.println((String)nm);

    }
}
```

If it is a normal for loop i could have done list.get(element index).toString() .
but how to do in enhanced for loop ??

Comment: Use ArrayList<String> instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't bypass type safety by calling `toString()` - you should use generics to start with:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now your `for` loop will compile (you can get rid of the cast in the `System.out.println` call btw) *and* the compiler will prevent you from adding a non-string to your list.

See the [Java generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for a starting point on generics, and the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information that you'll ever want to know :)

Comment: Great answer , i didn't thought that there would be a relation for Enhanced for loop and Generics . Thanks a lot .

Comment: I have one more question why people use List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); , rather than ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); ?

Comment: @yyyi777 See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @yyyi777: It's *generally* a good idea to code to the interface rather than the concrete type, as it shows that you're only *thinking* about it as "a list", and not using any `ArrayList`-specific members.

Comment: @yyyi777 List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>() is commented in http://cyclo.ps/books/Prentice.Hall.Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have not used Generics so you cannot safely do:

```
for (String nm : names)
```

As your ArrayList holds Objects, of which String IS A Object.  You must surely be using Java 5 or above, so use Generics to say your List will only contain Strings:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you didn't use Generics you would need to do:

```
   for (Object nm : names)
            System.out.println(nm);
```

Passing the Object to the println method will call its toString method anyhow.

**But use Generics!**